# Node: play two audio streams simultaneously

Tags: node.js, audio, raspberry-pi

I am developing an app where I want to play two mp3 files simultaneously and want to control the sound of each player separately. For this I need to control the loudness of each stream individually.

I wish I could do this with `node-speaker` and `pcm-volume` but I can't play parallel:

```
var Speaker = require("speaker");
var lame = require("lame");
var fs = require("fs");
var volume = require("pcm-volume");

var readable = fs.createReadStream("coming-out.mp3");

// see node-lame documentation for more information
var decoder1 = new lame.Decoder({
    channels: 2,
    bitDepth: 16,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    bitRate: 128,
    outSampleRate: 22050,
    mode: lame.STEREO
});

var masterSpeaker = new Speaker();


// Create a volume instance
var v1 = new volume();

v1.pipe(masterSpeaker); // pipe volume to speaker
decoder1.pipe(v1); // pipe PCM data to volume
readable.pipe(decoder1); // pipe file input to decoder


setTimeout(function() {
    // Create a volume instance
    // see node-lame documentation for more information
    var decoder2 = new lame.Decoder({
        channels: 2,
        bitDepth: 16,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        bitRate: 128,
        outSampleRate: 22050,
        mode: lame.STEREO
    });


    var v2 = new volume();
    v2.pipe(masterSpeaker); // pipe volume to speaker
    decoder2.pipe(v2); // pipe PCM data to volume
    readable.pipe(decoder2); // pipe file input to decoder
}, 2000);
```

Another possibility is to use external audio-player like the VLC player and control them by api from node, but vlc can not be opened multiple.

Are there any other linux audio player, working on raspberry pi and run multiple, which got an api to control the volume?

I would prefer the first possibility with node-speaker, because I don't want much dependencies.

Comment: can you elaborate to explain what happens when you try to play two sounds in // ? Have you tried to use two speaker instances ?

Comment: When I try two speaker instances the error `node main.js 
[../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:165] error: cannot open device default
node: pcm_params.c:2286: snd_pcm_hw_refine: Assertion `pcm && params' failed. ` appears.

Comment: indeed :bad: just thinking, have you tried to interlace them ?

Comment: interlace? sorry..? I've read that ALSA (which is used by node-speaker) only accept one audio source. I think that's why I get the error above. Better is using the pulseaudio lib, but the pulseaudio package for node is not working on arm-arch :(.

Comment: i meant interleave, but never mind. Maybe this could help ? https://github.com/substack/baudio/blob/master/index.js http://sox.sourceforge.net/